# How to convert blob url into mp3 audio in django

Tags: reactjs, django, api

So I'm working with recording audio from browser for which it is using Mic recorder API, now this Api after recording returns a blob url which I send to my project's django backend but the problem is how to get that audio file back from blob url at backend?

For your reference this is how it generate blob url:

```
const Mp3Recorder = new MicRecorder({ bitRate: 128 });

     stop = () => {
        Mp3Recorder.stop()
          .getMp3()
          .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
            const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log(blobURL);
            this.setState({ blobURL, isRecording: false });
            this.sendAudioFile(blobURL);
          })
          .catch((e) => console.log(e));
      };
```

and this is code for sending blob url to django backend

```
sendAudioFile = (url) => {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", url);
    return axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/recordings/", data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
      });
```

Pls suggest a good solution as I've already gone through various stackoverflow answers for similar questions but the problem is not getting solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found solution for this problem, just include this line of code to convert your blob url to mp3/.wav file and then send it to backend.

```
var wavfromblob = new File([blob], "incomingaudioclip.wav");
```

For more understanding refer this function code.

```
 Mp3Recorder.stop()
      .getMp3()
      .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(blobURL);
        var wavfromblob = new File([blob], "incomingaudioclip.wav");

        console.log(wavfromblob);
        const blobmp3 = new Blob();

        this.setState({ blobURL, isRecording: false });
        // this.createDownloadLink(blobURL);
        this.sendAudioFile(wavfromblob);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```